# MSI log file reader is not writing the results to the text file

Tags: python, logging

I have created a MSI log file reader that searches for specific log file names that a some installers leave behind during installation. It prints results separately in the shell but is not writing them to the created "MSI_Return.txt" file.

```
#Import Python Modules
import os
import fnmatch

#Create a find function to search the directories for the file name
def find(pattern, path):
    result = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for name in files:
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(name, pattern):
                result.append(os.path.join(root, name))
    return result

#Get the full list of LOG files from specified folder
infile = os.path.expanduser('~\\AppData\\Local\\Temp')
listoffiles = find("MSI*.LOG", infile)


#Process each file name in the file name array
key_phrases = ["Error",
              "Failed",
              "Exception", "Return Value 3"]
important = []
for eachfile in listoffiles:
    #Open the file
    with open(eachfile) as i:
        i = i.readlines()
    #Look through the lines for phrases
    #If a phrase is found, append it to an array
    for line in i:
        for phrase in key_phrases:
            if phrase in line:
                important.append(line)
                break

#Return output
MSI_Return = open('MSI_Return.txt','w')
MSI_Return.write('List of MSI files = ' + str(listoffiles))
MSI_Return.write('\n')
MSI_Return.write('Return of key lines from MSI files = ' + str(important))
MSI_Return.close
```

Any thoughts or input would be appreciated.

Comment: Reading [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs) might be helpful. I also suggest you use the built-in [`glob.glob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) function instead of your `find()` function.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I had forgotten to add () at the end of my close function. It now writes to the file properly.

Comment: That's good to hear. "There is nothing like looking, if you want to find something." `;¬)`